# Cannot make a POST request with curl_setopt for a JSON data

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I want to make the `PHP` equivalent for this `CURL` statement :

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u Administrator:Administrator -d '{"entity-type": "document", "name": "myNewDoc", "type": "File", "properties": {"dc:title": "My new doc", "file:content": {"upload-batch": "<myBatchId>", "upload-fileId": "0"}}}' http://192.168.128.101:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/path/Knowledge Base/workspaces/Archives Projets
```

Here is my code :

```
    /**
     * @Rest\Post("/api/getiterop", name="api_get_iterop")
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="sary", nullable=true)
     */
    public function getIteropForm(Request $req)
    {
        $userNameNuxeo = "api-kb";
        $mdpNuxeo = "zKqWQd3QhmigOLqVliqN#";
        // création et récupération du batch_id dans nuxeo
        $nuxeoBatchId = file_get_contents('http://192.168.128.101:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/', false, stream_context_create([
                                                        'http' => [
                                                                    'method' => 'POST',
                                                                    'header'  => array("Content-type: application/octet-stream", "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode ($userNameNuxeo.":".$mdpNuxeo)),
                                                                    'content' => http_build_query([]) // de la forme 'key1' => 'Hello world!', 'key2' => 'second value'
                                                                    ]
                                                ])
                                        );
        $nuxeoBatchId = json_decode($nuxeoBatchId, true);
        $nuxeoBatchId = $nuxeoBatchId['batchId'];
        // dossier pour mettre les fichiers uploadés
        $iteropFolderPath = "../iterop_files/" . $nuxeoBatchId . "/";
        $iteropFolder = true;
        if (file_exists($iteropFolderPath) === false) {
            $iteropFolder = mkdir($iteropFolderPath, 0777, true);
        }
        // déplacer les fichiers uploadés
        if (stripos($req->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'multipart') !== false) {
            $fichiers = $req->files;
            if (count($fichiers) > 0) {
                $fileIdx = 0;
                foreach($fichiers as $field_name => $fichier) {
                    if ($fichier != null) {
                        if ($iteropFolder === true) {
                            // déplacement du fichier iterop
                            $iteropFile = $fichier->move($iteropFolderPath, $fichier->getClientOriginalName());

                            // envoi du fichier associé au batch vers nuxeo , par chunks
                            $nbChunks = 5;
                            for($chunkIdx = 0 ; $chunkIdx < $nbChunks ; $chunkIdx++) {
                                $curl = curl_init('http://192.168.128.101:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/' . $nuxeoBatchId . '/' . $fileIdx);
                                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@' . realpath($iteropFolderPath . $fichier->getClientOriginalName()) . ';filename=' . $fichier->getClientOriginalName()));
                                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($userNameNuxeo.":".$mdpNuxeo), 'X-Upload-Type: chunked', 'X-Upload-Chunk-Index:'.$chunkIdx, 'X-Upload-Chunk-Count: '.$nbChunks, 'X-File-Name: ' . $fichier->getClientOriginalName(), 'X-File-Type: ' . $iteropFile->getMimeType(), 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream', 'X-File-Size: ' . filesize(realpath($iteropFolderPath . $fichier->getClientOriginalName()))));
                                curl_exec($curl);
                                curl_close($curl);
                            }
                            
                            // here is the bug
                            $name = $fichier->getClientOriginalName();
                            $pos = strrpos($name, '.');
                            $doc = array("entity-type" => "document",
                                        "name" => false === $pos ? $name : substr($name, 0, $pos),
                                        "type" => "File",
                                        "properties" => array("dc:title" => false === $pos ? $name : substr($name, 0, $pos),
                                                              "file:content" => array("upload-batch" => $nuxeoBatchId, "upload-fileId" => $fileIdx)
                                                            )
                                        );
                            $curl = curl_init('http://192.168.128.101:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/path/Knowledge Base/workspaces/Archives Projets');
                            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($doc));
                            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($userNameNuxeo.":".$mdpNuxeo), 'Content-Type: application/json'));
                            curl_exec($curl);
                            curl_close($curl);
                        }
                    }
                    $fileIdx++;
                }
            }
        }

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->setContent(json_encode(array("batchId" => $nuxeoBatchId)));
        return $response;
    }
```

But at runtime I get error : `HTTP Status 505 – HTTP Version Not Supported`

So what is wrong in my codes ?

Comment: so whats not clear about the message AND what does the curl_setopt documentation tell  you about http version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try this [resource](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php):

For example your request converted to this php scripts:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.128.101:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/path/Knowledge');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"entity-type\": \"document\", \"name\": \"myNewDoc\", \"type\": \"File\", \"properties\": {\"dc:title\": \"My new doc\", \"file:content\": {\"upload-batch\": \"<myBatchId>\", \"upload-fileId\": \"0\"}}}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'Administrator' . ':' . 'Administrator');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

2. And I am not sure about the spaces in url. Are you sure that url is correct and there should be spaces? According to [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

**The space character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs.**

3. If the url is correct try to encode it using this function [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)
4. Try to add **--head** options to your terminal curl request. So you will get supported HTTP version in response. And add new
   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, /*Correct http version here*/);`
   with equivalent value.

For example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0 );
```

Here is the [list](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.html) of available constants.

Comment: I get the same behavior

Comment: Are `--head` and `-H` not equivalent ?

Comment: No, `-H` is equivalent of `--header`. But I'm proposing to try with `--head` to headers of the response.